# How to resolve the error "type or namespace name could not be found in the global namespace"?

Tags: build, msbuild, namespaces

I am trying to build a project using TFS builds. The error being thrown is -"type or namespace name 'eCom' could not be found in the global namespace", even though it the 'eCom' dll gets created perfectly with the TFS builds. The builds are being run on a server. I even took the code to the build server, opened it there using visual studio and ran the build which executed without errors, but while running the build through the TFS builds, the build is failing. The build is working with visual studio, but not  with MSBuild.exe I found a lot of related questions on 'Stack overflow' itself, but nothing has worked yet. Please suggest what might be wrong. Another piece of information is that, recently dot net framework 4.6.2 was installed on the build server, build has been failing thereafter.

Comment: Can you build the project with command line locally? e.g : `msbuild test.sln /t:project /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86"`

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT, tried with command line too, but getting the same error there as well.

Comment: If it's not work locally, of course will not work in TFS. How did you build in TFS? which build task did you use in the definition? `Visual Studio Build` or `MS build`?  And is that working if changing the `Target framework` of the project  to  `4.6.1`?